# Do composite key indices improve performance of or clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table in MySQL with two columns

```
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
B varchar(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
```

The id being the PK.

I need to do a lookup in a query using either one of these. `id in (:idList) or B in (:bList)`

Would this query perform better if, there is a composite index with these two columns in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not.

Indexes can be used to look up values from the [leftmost columns in an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html):

> MySQL can use multiple-column indexes for queries that test all the columns in the index, or queries that test just the first column, the first two columns, the first three columns, and so on. If you specify the columns in the right order in the index definition, a single composite index can speed up several kinds of queries on the same table.

So, if you have a composite index on `id, B` fields (in this order), then the index can be used to look up values based on their `id`, or a combination of `id` **and** `B` values. But cannot be used to look up values based on `B` only. However, in case of an `or` condition that's what you need to do: look up values based on `B` only.

If both fields in the `or` condition are leftmost fields in an index, then MySQL attempts to do an [index merge optimisation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html), so you may actually be better off having separate indexes for these two fields.

Note: if you use innodb table engine, then there is no point in adding the primary key to any multi column index because innodb silently adds the PK to every index.

Answer (score 0):

For `OR` I dont think so.

Optimizer will try to find a match in the first side, if fail will try the second side. So Individual index for each search will be better.

For `AND` a composite index will help.

MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Of course you can always add the index and compare the explain plan.

[**MySQL Explain Plan**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't help for `AND` in this specific case, if the table is InnoDB, because indexes in InnoDB already include an implicit copy of the primary key at the end, and id is the primary key.  `INDEX(B,id)` would be funcionally equivalent to `INDEX(B)`, except it would presumably take up more space.  In any other case, you'd be correct about `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

The trick for optimizing `OR` is to use `UNION`.  (At least, it works well in some cases.)

```
( SELECT ... FROM ...  WHERE id IN (...) )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... FROM ...  WHERE B  IN (...) )
```

Notes:

- Need separate indexes on `id` and `B`.
- No benefit from any composite index (unless it is also "covering").
- Change `DISTINCT` to `ALL` if you know that there won't be any rows found by both the `id` and `B` tests.  (This avoids a de-dup pass.)
- If you need `ORDER BY`, add it after the SQL above.
- If you need `LIMIT`, it gets messier.  (This is probably not relevant for `IN`, but it often is with `ORDER BY`.)
- If the rows are 'wide' and the resultset has very few rows, it *may* be further beneficial to do

Something like this:

```
SELECT t...
    FROM t 
    JOIN (
           ( SELECT id FROM t  WHERE id IN (...) )
           UNION DISTINCT
           ( SELECT id FROM t  WHERE B  IN (...) )
         ) AS u  USING(id);
```

Notes:

- This needs `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and `INDEX(B, id)`.  (Actually there is no diff, as Michael pointed out.)
- The `UNION` is cheaper here because of collecting only `id`, not the bulky columns.
- The `SELECTs` in the `UNION` are faster because you should be able to provide "covering" indexes.
- `ORDER BY` would go at the very end.